# Can I use the tag column of fnd_lookup_values to store custom information?

Tags: oracle, oracle-ebs

I need to create a new lookup code in `fnd_lookup_values` and add additional information to the code. Oracle suggests that we can use arrribute1...attribute15 columns. But to use attribute1..15 columns, we need to do extra steps like creating DFF and attaching it to the current lookup code.

But also there is a `tag` column:

```sql
    create table FND_LOOKUP_VALUES
    (
      lookup_type         VARCHAR2(30) not null,
      language            VARCHAR2(30) not null,
      lookup_code         VARCHAR2(30) not null,
    ...
      attribute1          VARCHAR2(150),
    ...
      attribute14         VARCHAR2(150),
      attribute15         VARCHAR2(150),
      tag                 VARCHAR2(150)
    ...
```

Is it safe to use it in a custom oracle-ebs application to store additional information for lookup codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to use the tag column for custom purpose as there isn't any Oracle standard functionality depending on it.
The EBS online help reads:
Tag: Optionally enter in a tag to describe your lookup. The tag can be used to categorize lookup values.

Regards,
Andy